# Convex sublevels of non-convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

[image]

For a function to be quasi convex, the requirements are:

1. The domain is convex.
2. The sublevel sets are convex.

In my understanding, this function is not convex as it has a negative second derivative.

In the figure, the first condition is satisfied. Regarding the second condition, if we see the sublevel for $\beta$ i.e. $ S_\beta $ where $f(x)<\beta$, the section where the function has negative second derivative gets included. So why is the sublevel $ S_\beta $ considered as convex ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not convex it's quasiconvex. A quasiconvex function means that the inverse image of any set of the form $(-\infty,a)$ is convex. Graphically this means the inverse image of all the points below $\beta$ must be convex and since it is the interval $(-\infty,c)$ the function is quasiconvex.

Comment: In that case, the plot of $ abs ( sqrt(x) ) $ [link](https://imgur.com/a/BiUMwBI) will have discontinuities when defining the domain of sublevel $S_{\alpha}$. Why is it considered quasi convex then ?

Comment: @user3656142 there are no discontinuities in the inverse image of the sublevel set in that image. Note that the inverse image of the sublevel set given is the section between the two squiggly lines, not the set give by the squiggly lines. This is just an interval and so it's convex.